# model to fetch single result from db with jquery

Tags: codeigniter, jquery, model

I have a controller function which is called by jquery:

```
  function get_sku_prices(){
    $this->load->model('Sales_model');
    if (isset($_GET['term'])){
      $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
      $this->Sales_model->get_sku_price($q);
    }
}
```

The model, get_sku_price is:

```
  function get_sku_price($q){
    $this->db->select('price');
    $this->db->where('sku', $q);
    $query = $this->db->get('products');
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
      foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
        $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['price'])); //build an array
      }
      $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($row_set));

    }
  }
```

what I want, is to return the result of the above query(which is essentially `select price from products where sku=36113`) to the input variable 'price' on my view form.

My view syntax is:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>
         Capture blank Order
      </title>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>css/sales.css" />

<script type="text/javascript"> 
 function callAutocomplete(element) 
 { 
     $(element).autocomplete( 
     { 
         source: "sales/get_sku_codes", 
         messages: 
         { 
             noResults: '', 
             results: function() {} 
         }, 
         select: function( event, ui ) 
         {
             var selectedObj = ui.item; 
             $.post('sales/get_sku_prices', {data:selectedObj.value},function(result) { 
             $(ui).parent('tr').find('input[id^="pricepercube"]').val(result); 
             }); 
         } 
     }); 
 } 

 $(function() 
 { 
     var counter = 1; 
     jQuery("table.authors-list").on('change','input[name^="qty"]',function(event) 
     { 
         event.preventDefault(); 
         counter++; 
         var newRow = jQuery('<tr>'+ 
         ' <td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a></td>' + 
         ' <td><input type="text" id="product' + counter + '" name="product' + counter + '" /></td>' + 
         ' <td><input type="text" id="qty' + counter + '" name="qty' + counter + '" /></td>'+ 
         ' <td><input type="text" id="price' + counter + '" name="price' + counter + '" /></td>'+ 
         ' <td><input type="text" id="discount' + counter + '" name="discount' + counter + '"  /></td>'+ 
         ' <td valign=top><input type="checkbox" id="treated' + counter + '" name="treated' + counter + '" /></td>'+ 
         ' </tr>'); 
         jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow); 
         callAutocomplete("#product"+ counter); 
     }); 

$("#product").autocomplete( 
 { 
 source: "sales/get_sku_codes", 
 messages: 
 { 
 noResults: '', 
 results: function() {} 
 }, 
 select: function( event, ui ) 
 { 
 var selectedObj = ui.item; 
 $.post('<?=site_url("sales/get_sku_prices")?>', {data:selectedObj.value},function(result) 

 { 
 $("#price").val(result); 
 }); 
 } 
 });

 }); 

 </script>


  </head>
<body>

<table class="authors-list" border=0>
  <tr><td></td><td>Product</td><td>Qty</td><td>Price/Cube</td><td>Discount</td><td>treated</td></tr>
  <tr>
   <td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="product" name="product" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="qty" name="qty" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="price" name="price" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="discount" name="discount" /></td>
   <td valign="top" ><input type="checkbox" id="treated" name="treated" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Firefox returns a 200 OK message. you can see the post information contains the contents of the product input, but the returned HTML is blank?

**UPDATE**

mysql
[image]

post
[image]

blank html
[image]

is my model query correct? is the post being correctly passed tot he model? how can I verify this?

Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry Smudger, my comment wasn't technically correct I didn't read your model code too closely. See my answer below, this may or may not be the solution, the problem could well be that your query isn't returning any data. But as a rule of thumb it's best to output your data in the controller, not the model.

Comment: I started writing you an answer but I realized that you have many things turned to be either wrong or I just didn't understand.
your auto-complete has a post inside it which is calling your controller function. so I don't see your controller taking this input nor returning.
If I'm wrong then please explain it so I can help. if not then I can answer it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be outputing your data from the controller, not the model.

Controller:

```
function get_sku_prices(){
    $this->load->model('Sales_model');
    if (isset($_GET['term'])){
        $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
        $data = $this->Sales_model->get_sku_price($q);
        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode(data));
    } 
}
```

Model:

```
 function get_sku_price($q){
    $this->db->select('price');
    $this->db->where('sku', $q);
    $query = $this->db->get('products');
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
            $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['price'])); //build an array
       }
       return $row_set;
    }
  }
```

Further to the above, you are passing your data via AJAX as POST data, yet in your controller you are trying to receive data from the GET array.

Comment: Thanks Jeemusu, appreciate the advice. as you suspected though, the code above doesn't fix the issue. the POST information is still being sent however the HTML response is empty. you can check this out on http://www.isikhulu.co.za/testapp/.

Comment: The AJAX seems fine, as you say, your getting a response, it just doesn't contain what your expecting. I would check if your database query is returning any results. To debug it, I would `return query->result_array()` from your model, right after you do the get() call, and then add  `print_r($data);` to your controller. The response should then contain the results as they come out of the database. I added the code to my answer above as comments.

Comment: Still nothing being returned. no print_r array or output from controller. firebug showing post data being sent and still a blank html reply?

Comment: Try just echoing out a string in your controller, and see if you get the response?

Comment: so controller is: `function get_sku_prices(){
    $this->load->model('Sales_model');
    if (isset($_GET['term'])){
        $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
        $data = $this->Sales_model->get_sku_price($q);
  $data = "123.12";
        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode(data));
    }
}` and still no html output. am I missing something else?

Comment: Wait a minute! Are you trying to pass the data as ajax, or through the query string? Your controller is getting the data from the querystring, but your ajax is passing it as post? If you change that GET to a POST, it will probably work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26616/discussion-between-smudger-and-jeemusu)

Answer (score 2):

You are passing data inside `$.post` and getting it as `term`.

Change

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])){
```